# Как расставить запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, частицы

*Но(,) ведь(,) неважно кто твой друг, если он настоящий.*

Как правильно расставить запятые? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Диана, если нужны более подробные разъяснения, я могу дополнить ответ. Если это не требуется и ответ помог решить вопрос, Вы можете отметить ответ стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принять его галочкой. И на будущее: на этом сайте желательно приводить **своё решение** вопроса,  иначе его могут посчитать за домашнее задание и закрыть.

Answer (score 3):

*Но ведь неважно, кто твой друг, если он настоящий*.

1. Частица [***ведь***](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/ved) не требует постановки знаков препинания.
2. Запятые разделяют три простых предложения в составе сложного.
   Их грамматические основы: ***неважно, кто друг, он настоящий***.